# Error in fetching rows from table using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This code was working fine yesterday , and suddenly started showing error today..
The die('Error') gives out error when displaying the users with profile pictures
Thanks in advance for the help ... i am learning php so will convert to pdo later

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
// Create connection
$conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password) or die('Error1');;

mysql_select_db("motorklq_glmindb",$conn) or die('Error2');


$result = mysql_query("SELECT adno,fname,lname,profilepic,gscore FROM gtable WHERE contest!='on' ORDER BY gscore DESC  LIMIT 3") or die('Error');;

echo "<table><tr><th></th><th>gScore Leader</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
echo "<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Image</th><th>Glamour</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<tr><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['profilepic'] ) . '"  width="32" height="32">'."</td><td>".$row['gscore']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Link to the db https://www.dropbox.com/s/dv8vhla0fxhw2p7/db.png

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated an unsecure. Use mysqli_* or PDO instead!

Comment: have you tried putting the table name in 'gtable'

Comment: gtable is the table name ,and insertion works fine now .. but not sure what happened to the code for showing the result

Comment: Most likely the set of columns is wrong This should lead to an error. Your problem: you don't do _any_ error handling. That way you do not see the error. Please take a look at the way the mysql extension displays errors. You MUST implement error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT adno,
```

Change to

```
SELECT idno,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mis-typed **adno** for **idno** in your select query.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

delete extra ; from query

```
$conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password) or die('Error1');;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT adno,fname,lname,profilepic,gscore FROM gtable WHERE contest!='on' ORDER BY gscore DESC  LIMIT 3") or die('Error');;
```

to

```
$conn=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password) or die('Error1');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT idno,fname,lname,profilepic,gscore FROM gtable WHERE contest!='on' ORDER BY gscore DESC  LIMIT 3") or die('Error');
```